# How do I free a *char allocated via FFI in Rust?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm calling the LLVM API via Rust's FFI. `LLVMPrintModuleToString` [uses strdup to create a string](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Core_8cpp_source.html#l00205). However, when I wrap the pointer in a `CString`, I get an error when Rust drops it.

```
#![feature(cstr_memory)]
use std::ffi::CString;

extern crate llvm_sys as llvm;

fn main() {
    let llvm_ir_cstring;
    unsafe {
        let module = llvm::core::LLVMModuleCreateWithName(b"nop\0".as_ptr() as *const _);
        let llvm_ir_char_ptr = llvm::core::LLVMPrintModuleToString(module);
        llvm::core::LLVMDisposeModule(module);
        llvm_ir_cstring = CString::from_ptr(llvm_ir_char_ptr);
    }

    println!("llvm_ir_cstring: {:?}", llvm_ir_cstring);
}
```

Valgrind error:

```
==10413== Invalid read of size 4
==10413==    at 0x4870586: pthread_mutex_lock (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.21.so)
==10413==    by 0x17F89B: je_arena_dalloc_small (in /home/wilfred/projects/bfc/target/debug/bfc)
==10413==    by 0x178C30: je_sdallocx (in /home/wilfred/projects/bfc/target/debug/bfc)
==10413==    by 0x10FA57: heap::imp::deallocate::h1fb92d59333c497bkja (heap.rs:268)
==10413==    by 0x10F999: heap::deallocate::h5680e3fedc9e96320da (heap.rs:89)
==10413==    by 0x10F929: heap::exchange_free::h452463f962f7ec23kfa (heap.rs:131)
==10413==    by 0x10F8C5: Box$LT$$u5b$u8$u5d$$GT$::drop.1769::haf7017472635c7cf (in /home/wilfred/projects/bfc/target/debug/bfc)
==10413==    by 0x10F836: std..ffi..c_str..CString::drop.1766::h04d2b3db8d468f0c (in /home/wilfred/projects/bfc/target/debug/bfc)
==10413==    by 0x10F5FF: main::h04b7feb343e229ccgaa (in /home/wilfred/projects/bfc/target/debug/bfc)
==10413==    by 0x16DBCA: rt::unwind::try::try_fn::h2403085009213705177 (in /home/wilfred/projects/bfc/target/debug/bfc)
==10413==    by 0x16FF5A: rust_try_inner (in /home/wilfred/projects/bfc/target/debug/bfc)
==10413==    by 0x16FF33: rust_try (in /home/wilfred/projects/bfc/target/debug/bfc)
==10413==  Address 0x1d684 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Why is this? What's the correct way to handle a `*char` from a C API?

Comment: Have a C function free it, and call that C function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the function's documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/group__LLVMCCoreModule.html#gad150d942dc9f49238f57cb89464c01df):

> Use LLVMDisposeMessage to free the string.

In the general case, if you call a function in a library that allocates memory, you should call another function in that library that frees the memory; this should generally be documented as part of the function's contract.

If the documentation for a function tells you to use `free`, then you'll have a problem if your application is not linking with the `free` corresponding to the library's `malloc` (e.g. your application links with msvcr120, but the library links with msvcr100). This is the reason why good libraries provide a method to deallocate resources that it allocates for you.

The default memory allocator in Rust is not C's `malloc`, but another allocator called [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/). `CString` assumes the string was allocated with Rust's memory allocator, so when `CString`'s destructor runs, it runs jemalloc's `free` (you can tell from the `je_`-prefixed functions in your call stack), but it fails because the string wasn't allocated with jemalloc's `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks, that's really illuminating.